# hide the actual name of a file inside a folder using .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, hide, cpanel

suppose, I have an index100.php file inside folder1 (eg. folder1/index100.php). Is there any way so that if the user types folder1/index.php, then it will automatically redirect to folder1/index100.php? 
How can it be done using .htaccess file?

Comment: Do you really mean an _external_ "redirect"? Or an _internal_ "rewrite"? What should the user see in the browser's address bar?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show `index100.php` insted of `index.php` as your directory handler, you can use `DirectoryIndex` directive in `/folder1htaccess`

```
DirectoryIndex index100.php
```

This will serve you the `/index100.php` if you visit `http://example.com/folder1`

If you actually want to redirect `/folder1/index.php` to `/folder1/index100.php` then use the following rule in your `/folder1/. htaccess` .

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /folder1/index100.php [L,R]
```